# Regex replace words which are not inside anchor tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I'm trying to find a regex that finds all words that are not within anchor tags. I already have a variant that works quite well, but unfortunately it doesn't work if the tags are nested.

Here is my expression:

`(.*?)(\bFoobar\b(?!([^<>]*[^<>]*|[^<>]*)(<\/a|>)))(.*$)`

This works, it finds Foobar:

```
<strong>Foobar</strong> bar baz
```

This works as well, it does not find Foobar, cause its inside anchor tag:

```
<a href="foobar.com">Foobar</a> bar baz
```

But this does not work, it finds Foobar:

```
<a href="foobar.com"><strong>Foobar</strong></a> bar baz
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: regex is not a great candidate for such a feature.  Is this running in a browser or node?.

Comment: Actually, it has already been implemented in golang. I have now done it with an html tokenizer, but still wanted to know whether there is a solution via regex. I only added the Javascript flag because golang doesn't have a lookahead regex natively.